# AWS Sagemaker - Training on Video Stills v Images

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am using sagemaker, GroundTruth, to build training data. The data will then be used to create model for object detection across videos. I want to understand the best way of doing this.

At this stage I am going to using humans (our team) to label stills to mark out the objects.

Questions:

1. Data Format: What is the difference between uploading frames and then selecting the data format as "video frame" v "images"?  Aren't they both images - so does it make a difference to the training set up?

[Sage Maker Data Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUxwL.jpg)

2. Training Now v Later: At the moment we have capacity to be training the data set, though we are a long way off building the model. We know what labels we are going to be using what we are detecting. Is there any reason why we can't do the training now? Would it be a waste of resources -without knowing more about the future model?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can help with the first question. If you select "images" it will treat each image as single, distinct image such as a bird, dog, fish, etc.

If you select one of the video objects it will treat the images as a sequence of frames give you access the the video specific features such as object tracking across frames and using the "predict next feature". You would use "video frames" if you have already extracted the video frames using a tool like FFmpeg. You would chose "video files" if you want to upload frames and have GroundTruth extract the frames for you. The frame extraction worked very well for me when I used the video files option.